# in which senarios that just compile the source file but not link the object files

Tags: gcc

in what usage circumstance use "-c" option in gcc to only compile source files to object files but not link them? Could anybody share some usage scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is when you're linking against external, pre-compiled libraries, eg:

```sh
$ gcc -c myfile.c
$ gcc myfile.o precompiled_object.o -lprecompiled_lib
```

The two steps can happen in different parts of a build pipeline, or in different pipelines / components (e.g. myfile.o may be re-used to produce different products, which is actually another use case).

Another example is when you're not the one doing the linking e.g. you supply object files and a third party is doing the linking.

Another example is when you only want to check your code (the current file) compiles, instead of (re-) building the entire project, which may take long.

Comment: Could you share the exact steps of the first example?

Comment: @michael_J make sure to include credit if you're writing it somewhere ;)